# function returns false - but I'm sure it should be true

Tags: php, string, function, if-statement

I have this string:

```
$currentpath = basename(__FILE__);
```

If I write

```
echo $currentpath;
```

It returns navleft.php

Now my function:

```
function colorButton() {
    if($currentpath == "navleft.php") {
        echo "navbuttonon";
    } else {
        echo "navbuttunoff";
    }
}
```

but if I call the function

```
colorButton();
```

I always get navbuttonoff.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Are you shure you're shure? `:D`

Answer (score 4):

You need to learn about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). `$currentpath` is not available to `colorButton` unless you pass it as a parameter (or use evil things like `global`):

```
function colorButton($currentpath) {
if($currentpath == "navleft.php") {
    echo "navbuttonon";
} else {
    echo "navbuttunoff";
}
}
```

Perfect example from the manual:

```
<?php
$a = 1; /* global scope */ 

function test()
{ 
    echo $a; /* reference to local scope variable */ 
} 

test();
?>
```

> This script will not produce any output because the echo statement refers to a local version of the $a variable, and it has not been assigned a value within this scope.

Comment: What a stupid I am... Sorry this was basilar... :-( sorry again!

Comment: No worries. We've all been there. :)

Answer (score 0):

You either need to:

**1. Use a global**

```
function colorButton() {
    global $currentpath;

    if($currentpath == "navleft.php") {
        echo "navbuttonon";
    } else {
        echo "navbuttunoff";
    }
}
```

OR, the better solution:

**2. Pass the path in as an argument**

```
function colorButton($currentpath) {

    if($currentpath == "navleft.php") {
        echo "navbuttonon";
    } else {
        echo "navbuttunoff";
    }
}

colorButton($currentpath);
```

---

**Things you should learn about:**

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

You can't call vars from function like this...

It should be like

```
<?
$currentpath = 'navleft.php';
function colorButton() {

  global $currentpath;

  if($currentpath == "navleft.php") {
    echo "navbuttonon";
  } else {
    echo "navbuttunoff";
  }
}
colorButton();
```

OR like this

```
<?
$currentpath = 'navleft.php';
function colorButton($currentpath) {

  if($currentpath == "navleft.php") {
    echo "navbuttonon";
  } else {
    echo "navbuttunoff";
  }
}
colorButton($currentpath);
```